# Why was this question marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicates

[Use system fonts (Mac OS) while using book template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262772/use-system-fonts-mac-os-while-using-book-template)

I understand that it is a question about changing the font, but the asker was using the correct code to change font. My answer explains why it doesn’t work in this case, a problem which people may well have using fontspec on OS X.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see, the community agreed with you and the post got reopened. Thanks, it was a good catch!